# Navigation Bar Strange Behavior

Tags: android

I am using the following to change the colour of `navigation bar`

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!--<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>-->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>    
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>    
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!-- Try chnaging the above line settings -->
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>
```

The results on my PIXEL Device which is running Android Pie are the following

[image]

This is good, but on my android devices running Android 7.1 are the following

[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

In addition, I think the issue is in `<!--<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>` section